# React-Native Image Viewer?

Tags: ios, node.js, react-native

I've been looking for a component in React Native that handles displaying multiple images in full-screen mode that a user can swipe through, pinch and zoom, and dismiss by swiping down. This seems like it would be a popular component but I haven't been able to find anything that does that.

The only thing that seems to be close to what I'm looking for is using a ScrollView and implementing the `maximumZoomScale` and `pagingEnabled` options.

Does anyone know if an npm package exists to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [react-native-lightbox](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-lightbox) component has the features you've requested, but they are not yet in the latest released version.

You can try out the features in the [`react-native-lightbox/navigator-refactor`](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-lightbox/tree/navigator-refactor) branch and perhaps help with its development - the last commits to that branch are in March, so it's not likely to be released soon.

Comment: Great suggestion. I'll checkout the dev version and look forward to the live release!

Comment: @whimsyBear did you get that branch to work? I've been trying to without any luck.

Comment: @toddmetheny yeah the dev version worked well for me. Not sure the current status of this feature.